# jQuery UI autocomplete show results before search

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I want in my project to show some first results before I focus autocomplete input. Those results should work the same way as results of autocomplete ajax request.

Can I do this by standart options of autocomplete or I should write equal javascript code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set the `minLength` option to `0`. If you want results to appear as soon as the field is focused into, you could write a simple event handler to accomplish that:

```
$("input").autocomplete({
    source: /* source */,
    minLength: 0
}).on("focus", function () {
    $(this).autocomplete("search", '');
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/mLSjL/

**Edit:** If you want to show the suggestion list immediately, try showing it on the `create` event of the autocomplete widget:

```
$("input").autocomplete({
    source: /* source */,
    minLength: 0,
    create: function () {
        $(this).autocomplete("search", '');
    }
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/CVUWV/