# jQuery Autocomplete Plugin: show on focus

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-autocomplete

I have used [this extension](http://jquery.bassistance.de/autocomplete/demo/). How do I make the extension show on focus ?

I have tried this script:

```
$("input").autocomplete({
    source: /* source */,
    minLength: 0,
    create: function () {
        $(this).autocomplete("search", '');
    }
});
```

which taken from
[jQuery UI autocomplete show results before search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758821/jquery-ui-autocomplete-show-results-before-search)

but it doesn't success.

currently it use jQuery 1.5.2 and currently upgrading jQuery is not an option, because it have to change many part of code.

Comment: 1. is it really a good idea to show everything on focus? hopefully you dont have a lot of data. 2. why dont u use the onfocus event ?

Comment: But it works here: http://jsfiddle.net/mLSjL/

Comment: "jQuery 1.5.2"  Well, you are calling for issues then

Comment: @roasted, i use jQuery 1.5.2, the example use jQuery 1.7 which autocomplete is included.

Comment: Ya, i see your update. You should migrate to newer jquery version, this is the only answer i can think of.

Comment: you should really think to update your jquery version or else create your own autocomplete plugin if you are good in javascript.